# TypeScript project with references

Tags: typescript, project-structure

I use [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) to reference "shared" project from "front" and "back" ones.

**tsc -v:** `Version 3.3.3`

**Project structure:**

```
./{MY_PROJECT}.code-workspace   /* the only file in this level */
./back
./back/tsconfig.json
./shared/src/
./shared/
./shared/tsconfig.json
./shared/src/
./front
./front/tsconfig.json
./front/src
```

I am tring to import a module to `./front/src/article-view-model.ts` from the shared project:

```
import Article from "@shared/src/article";            // alias path
import Article from "../../shared/src/article"; // full relative path
export default class ArticleViewModel {
}
```

The following errors are shown immediately in VS Code GUI:

For alias path:

> Cannot find module '@shared/src/article'. ts(2307)

For full relative path:

> Output file '../../shared/src/article' has not been built from source file 'c:/{SOMEWHERE_IN_MY_PC}/shared/src/article.ts'. ts(6305)

Intellisense (VS Code) does work for both alias and relative options:

[image: Intellisense]

If i try ignore the errors and build, it fails with that:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:1296
>               throw e;
>               ^
>
> Error: Debug Failure. False expression.
>       at mergeSymbol (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:25861:26)
>       at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:25960:47
>       at Map.forEach ()
>       at mergeSymbolTable (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:25958:20)
>       at initializeTypeChecker (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:48653:21)
>       at Object.createTypeChecker (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:25711:9)
>       at getDiagnosticsProducingTypeChecker (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:71398:93)
>       at Object.getGlobalDiagnostics (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:71755:72)
>       at Object.getGlobalDiagnostics (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:73528:86)
>       at buildSingleProject (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node_modules\typescript\lib\tsc.js:75803:127)

**./front/tsconfig.json contents:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "module": "amd",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "out": "./lib/front-bundle.js",
        "paths": {"@shared/*" : ["../shared/*"]},
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "watch": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
    ],
    "references": [
        {
            "path": "../shared"
        }
    ]
}
```

**./shared/tsconfig.json contents:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "out": "./lib/shared-bundle.js",
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "watch": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it little after my last activity here, but i wasn't 100% sure if that happened due to the following changes. I am posting it here anyway, as there are still new views and votes, so it may be valuable for others:

That was the change:

In **./shared/tsconfig.json contents**

I added

```json
{
   "outDir": "./lib/",
   ...
   "rootDir": "./src",
}
```

to give:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "composite": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "outDir": "./lib/", <-------------
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "rootDir": "./src", <-------------
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "watch": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*.ts",
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 49):

Found this when searching for "typescript references has not been built from source file".
My mistake was that I was running `tsc -p tsconfig.json` when I [should've been using the `--build` flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#caveats-for-project-references): `tsc --build tsconfig.json`. If you run with `-p` TypeScript will not build the referenced projects. Only if you run with `--build`.

Answer (score 8):

I arrived here trying to solve a "has not been built from source file" error. Turned out a `tsc` watch process hadn't properly exited, so I had two instances fighting over the files. Just in case anyone else runs into the same issue

Answer (score 3):

I'm able to reproduce the errors you get *if* I have an errant `tsconfig.json` in the directory that contains `front`, `back` and `shared`. In this case running `tsc -b` will pick up the errant `tsconfig.json` in the current directory and since it is not configured with the right `paths` or anything else, the compilation fails with the same errors you get.

Otherwise, if I use your files and issue `tsc -b front` instead of `tsc -b`, it compiles without error.

The reason VSCode does not run into trouble is that in order to provide completion, TypeScript editors (normally) use a tool provided by TypeScript called `tsserver`. And when an editor gives a file path to `tsserver`, `tsserver` gets a relevant `tsconfig.json` by looking in the directory that contains the source file, and then up into the parent directory, and so on, until it finds a `tsconfig.json` file. So when VSCode works on `front/src/foo.ts` and asks `tsserver` to provide completion, `tsserver` looks in `front/src` which has no matching file, and then `front`, and finds the `tsconfig.json` there.

Comment: I don't have a `tsconfig.json` file in `./` folder. Updated question a bit.

Comment: If you have a `tsconfig.json` file higher in the directory hierarchy it would also be picked up.

Comment: There isn't in any level

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this error can be caused by many things. For me the problem was that I deleted the output directory in the `shared` project without deleting the `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` file. It seems that this file is some sort of cache to prevent referencing projects from rebuilding the `shared` project.

Comment: `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` is such a pain, it's always doing this to me. What's the point of caching anything if you simply need to delete it all the time to get anything to work!

Answer (score 1):

This totally doesn't answer your question directly, but I feel it might still be useful to offer an alternative.

One way to solve this in a 'more standard' fashion, would be to make your 3 codebases all an NPM package.

This way your import would be something like `@vendor/shared/foo` instead of `../../../../shared/src/article`.

Using `npm link` it's easy to work on a project cross-dependency.

You don't technically even need to modify your source structure (although maybe you want to). The `shared` dependency just gets softlinked via `node_modules`.

Comment: As an advice, I should say that using `npm link` is not always the best way to go.
I've found some issue since *symbolic links* are used, and so dependencies cannot be flattened, leading to differences between final build and development. 

It's a cool tool sure for development, but not always the best solution. Just my two cents!

Comment: @leonardfactory that's good to know! Usually having 'npm link' on is a temporary state for me until I can stop doing cross-repo development. I can definitely see that that can become an issue.

Comment: I try to use yalc for local development, It works like npm link, has flattening support and a nice watch mode, I suggest it!

Comment: @leonardfactory - "... symbolic links are used, and so dependencies cannot be flattened" needs a little more explanation to make sense.  Symbolic links enable dependencies to be flattened - that's the whole point.  There is one caveat - at least for yarn - links for bin executables are not created during "yarn install [--offline] [--force]" unless the path in package.json::"bin{name:path}" actually exists.  To get around that "yarn install [--offline] [--force]"  must be called again after compilation has completed successfully, before the executables are called.

Comment: This answer is vastly underrated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling from root folder, try to add a local `tsconfig.json` file with all `references` set up, i.e. `references: { path: './shared' }`. Otherwise, tsc will not find relevant project to build.

Furthermore not having a root `tsconfig.json` will *not* allow VSCode GUI to work properly as it looks for root `tsconfig.json` (this is the state last time I checked it, here you can find the [related issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12463)).

The error seems to be related to missing file. If you can provide further details about the building steps you take, I can try to check it better

Answer (score 0):

## Check to Make Sure You Have a .tsconfig File in the Referenced Directory

This error will also occur if the .tsconfig file does not exist in the target directory. The error message is misleading as the directory can exist but gives you an impression it cannot find it.

Also, if `"composite": true` is not present in the .tsconfig file you will get another error.